# $: command not found

Tags: command-line, system-installation, chromium

So basically I am trying to install Chromium OS on my device from: http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools and then ran the command:

```
$ export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

and then the error came up

```
$: command not found
```

I looked on many websites and I don't seem to understand what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command again without the `$`, it's just the prompt to tell you the shell is ready for your input.

```
export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

Answer (score 3):

The command I believe should just be

```
 export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

In tutorials they use $ to show run following command from command prompt. I think you used it as part of your command like this.

```
 $ export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

Comment: The backticks around `pwd` are important.

Comment: Yes I know. I didn't realize didn't carry over with my copy paste in Android for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Delete the $ symbol from your command - it's just a common sign saying that what follows after it should be typed into bash (terminal).